# R packge sp to sf QGIS 3.14

Tags: qgis, r, sf, sp

I have several scripts written in R language with package "sp" for Qgis. However I am stuck in the old versions (2.18) because whenever I use this same package in current versions 3.14 the script has an error. What alternatives could i do to work around this problem?
I didn't write the scripts, I only use them.
I've been researching and the "sp" package has been replaced by "sf" but I don't have the cognitive ability to rewrite all the scripts.

This is 1 of the 12 scripts I use in version 2.18.
When I try to run in version 3.14 I get this error.

```
##Determina_zonas_de_manejo=group
##Raster_de_Entrada=raster
##Poligono_mascara=vector
##Quantidade_de_Celulas_para_Remover_das_Bordas=number 0
##Raster_Corte_por_Mascara=output raster

library(raster)
library(sp)
require(rgdal)
library(rgeos)

raster_in  <- Raster_de_Entrada
pol_mask <- Poligono_mascara
rm_bord <- Quantidade_de_Celulas_para_Remover_das_Bordas


#raster_in <- brick('C:/Dados/ManejoPrecisao/UGD_geodata/ndvi.tif')[[1]]
#pol_file <- 'C:/Dados/ManejoPrecisao/UGD_geodata/talhao01.shp'
#pol_mask <- readOGR(dirname(pol_file), strsplit(basename(pol_file), '[.]')[[1]][1] )
#rm_bord = 1

cel_tam <- res(raster_in)[1]
rm_bord_tam <- rm_bord * cel_tam

rm_bord_buf <- gBuffer(pol_mask, width= -rm_bord_tam)

if(rm_bord == 0){
  crop_in <- crop(raster_in, extent(pol_mask), snap = 'out')
  raster_out <- mask(crop_in, pol_mask)
  Raster_Corte_por_Mascara = raster_out
} else{
  crop_in <- crop(raster_in, extent(rm_bord_buf), snap = 'out')
  raster_out <- mask(crop_in, rm_bord_buf)
  Raster_Corte_por_Mascara = raster_out
}
```

[image]

Comment: The sp package has not been replaced by sf so, that is not the problem. Unfortunately you do not provide enough information for us to troubleshoot anything. We need access to the scripts, version information on QGIS, R and the required packages. Also, knowing what errors are being produced would be helpful as well.

Comment: Sorry for the mistake, I updated the question with the information. Thanks. @JeffreyEvans

Comment: To go from sf to sp use `as(x, "Spatial")` and sp to sf `as(x, "sf")` but, be aware of multipart geometries. You can nest as coercion directly into a function without creating a new object first eg., `gBuffer(as(x, "Spatial"), width=1000)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error appears to be coming from this line:

```
rm_bord_buf <- gBuffer(pol_mask, width= -rm_bord_tam)
```

and is basically saying it doesn't know what to do with `pol_mask` because it is an `sf` object (that's the `"unable to find an inherited method..."` message).

`gBuffer` comes from the `rgeos` package and that expects `sp` objects. I suspect that QGIS is providing vector layers as `sf` objects and not `sp` objects, and that breaks the script.

To fix, attach the `sf` package and convert vector layers from `sp` to `sf`:

```
library(raster)
library(sp)
require(rgdal)
library(rgeos)
library(sf) # QGIS is giving us `sf` objects

raster_in  <- Raster_de_Entrada
pol_mask <- as(Poligono_mascara,"Spatial") # convert to `sp` from `sf`
rm_bord <- Quantidade_de_Celulas_para_Remover_das_Bordas
```

That *might* fix the scripts, or it might only get it as far as the next error message. Try it and see.